# Where are Dia diagram shapes located on Linux?

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, icons, diagram, dia

I recently installed this wonderful diagram creation tool [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/), and also downloaded the [AWS Diagram icons](https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/icons/) in SVG format.

I tried to `locate *.shape` (because all of them need to end in `*.shape`) but couldn't find anything, only unrelated files.

Does anyone know where Dia `*.shape` are located? I really want to add all AWS Icons at once, instead of adding them one by one from Dia UI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### How to find specific files, installed by applications

Found them on Ubuntu 16.04 in `/usr/share/dia/shapes`. Ubuntu or Lubuntu  shouldn't make a difference. You can find out where files are installed with the help of

```
dpkg-query -S .shape
```

to look for specific patterns. This shows that all `.shape` files are in `/usr/share/dia/shapes`. They are grouped however in many subdirectories.

---

**Note** however that for each and every `.shape` file, there is a corresponding `.png` file, most likely to represent the shape in the menu:

[image]

---

See also [man dpkg-query](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg-query.1.html)

```
   -S, --search filename-search-pattern...
          Search  for  packages  that own files corresponding to the given
          pattern.  Standard shell wildcard characters can be used in  the
          pattern,  where  asterisk (*) and question mark (?) will match a
          slash, and blackslash (\) will be used as an escape character.

          If the first character in the filename-search-pattern is none of
          ‘*[?/’  then it will be considered a substring match and will be
          implicitly surrounded by ‘*’ (as in  *filename-search-pattern*).
          If  the  subsequent  string contains any of ‘*[?\’, then it will
          handled like a glob pattern, otherwise any trailing ‘/’ or  ‘/.’
          will be removed and a literal path lookup will be performed.

          This  command  will  not  list extra files created by maintainer
          scripts, nor will it list alternatives.
```

To find out where an application installed its files, use (in this case):

```
dpkg-query -L dia-shapes
```

#### Finding out with synaptic

Also Synaptic offers help how to find out.

- Search for `dia, right-click on the package
- Click on "Installed Files" (tab)